# XCode 5 - the local git repository could not be reached

Tags: xcode, git

I created a project with **local** git repository using XCode 5 (preview 6), made some changes and tried to commit, and finally got the message "**The repository 'HelloWorld2' could not be reached, please verify that the repository is online and reachable and try again**".

The same message is also shown when the Refresh Status menu item under Source Control menu is clicked.

Actually, I have XCode 4.5 installed and run side by side with 5.0, but the issue does **not** exist when the project is opened using Xcode 4.5.  Also, the commit action works fine as well via command line.

Comment: Xcode 5 is still under development, and it's normal to encounter some bugs. Moreover is also under NDA, so you should't discuss it on SO. You'll find more luck on http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 5.0 Final

Comment: Yeah. I still encounter the issue occasionally in Xcode 5.0 final, however it will disappear after I reboot the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps in the tracking down of this problem, but here goes anyway:

I have been connecting to a local network git repository perfectly well for a number of months, but I encountered this problem later yesterday and nothing I did seemed to improve the situation. That included:

- Rebooting both the development machine and the server;
- Reinstalling Xcode from the App Store;
- Re-cloning the project from the git command line (which could see the repository perfectly well);
- Checking out the repository from Xcode (I was able to check out but every other operation, such as , Commit, Refresh Status etc. seemed to cause the problem...)
- Manipulation the repository with SourceTree (which could also see it fine).

Eventually I stumbled across a solution to my local issue. If I launch Xcode with a wired and wireless network enabled then I can't see the repository. If I close it, disable wifi and relaunch it then I can.

I've not had much opportunity to work out what the difference is (especially as the wifi connects to the same network and is the secondary choice for networking) but it does seem to fix it.

Hope that might help others and hopefully I can find a real explanation soon!

Dave,